# Различные цвета текста для ввода и вывода в cmd.exe

Tags: windows, cmd

Нужно выставить для ввода один цвет, для вывода другой.
Есть ли альтернативный cmd с возможностью таких настроек?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

> Установка цветов по умолчанию для текста и фона в текстовых окнах.
>
> COLOR [цвета]
>
> цвета       Атрибуты цветов для текстовых окон
>
> Атрибуты цветов задаются в виде ДВУХ шестнадцатеричных цифр -- первая
>   задает цвет фона, а вторая определяет цвет текста.  Каждая цифра может
>   иметь следующие значения:
>
> ```
> 0 = Черный      8 = Серый
> 1 = Синий       9 = Светло-синий
> 2 = Зеленый     A = Светло-зеленый
> 3 = Голубой     B = Светло-голубой
> 4 = Красный     C = Светло-красный
> 5 = Лиловый     D = Светло-лиловый
> 6 = Желтый      E = Светло-желтый
> 7 = Белый       F = Ярко-белый
> ```
>
> Если аргумент не указан, команда восстанавливает исходный выбор
>   цветов, каким он был на момент запуска CMD.EXE.  Это значение
>   извлекается из текущего текстового окна, из значения ключа /T или из
>   значения параметра реестра DefaultColor.

Это из справки к команде `color`.

Вам надо просто дать команду

```
color 0a
```

например, дайт "хацкерский" терминал - кислотно-зеленые буквы на черном фоне.

Comment: Мне нужно, чтобы **ввод** был одним цветом, а **вывод** - другим. Посмотрите картинку.

Comment: @kirman bash не пробовали?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. А для винды есть? Там точно можно настроить цвета на ввод-вывод? Вы знаете или интересуетесь?

Answer (score 2):

Нашел альтернативную программу в которой можно выбрать цвета на ввод, вывод и ошибки. Называется Take Command.

Answer (score 1):

Можно так

in:

```
@echo off
call :colored "Print me in red!" Red
call :colored "Print me in blue!" Blue

pause >nul
exit

:colored
%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe write-host -foregroundcolor %2 %1
```

out:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Через [Cmder](http://cmder.net) можно запускать как cmd, так и PowerShell с возможностью открытия нескольких вкладок и кучей настроек.

[image]

Comment: Ага, симпатичная программка. Только я рано обрадовался. Когда запускаю sqlite в этой или другой программе где ввод-вывод разными цветами, то все что происходит в sqlite - считается выводом и всё одним цветом печатается.